# ng-include reloads the whole page in IE9

Tags: angularjs

I have a main.html page and using ng-include I load the content of child.html, whenever I access the main.html in IE9 it reloads the whole page, however it works perfectly fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of URL containing # symbol.